# Why does each pod get reinstalled when I run pod install?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

When I run pod install on my project, each pod in my pod file gets installed/reinstalled.  On other projects I've been involved with when you run pod install only the newly added items to the podfile get installed.

For example, assuming my podfile already had AFNetworking, SDWebImage and SVProgressHUD, and I had recently added Facebook-iOS-SDK, running pod install outputs this:

```
-> Installing AFNetworking
-> Installing SDWebImage
-> Installing SVProgressHUD
-> Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK
```

when I would expect it to output something like this instead (and proceed much faster than it does):

```
-> Using AFNetworking
-> Using SDWebImage
-> Using SVProgressHUD
-> Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK
```

I've tried this with both version 0.34.2 and 0.33.1 of cocoapods with no luck.  My podfile in my project looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
xcodeproj 'ProjectName.xcodeproj'
platform :ios, '8.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.19.0'
pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk', '1.7.1'
pod 'MD5Digest'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'SDWebImage-ProgressView'
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'STTwitter'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

This issue is one of out two issues I'm having with cocoapods.  I think they might be related so I'm adding a link to the other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333345/why-does-running-pod-install-download-more-files-than-specified-in-the-podspec-f

Comment: Have you used 'pod update' at all?

Comment: Yup. It also causes all the pods to reinstall (even when there isn't a new version of the currently installed pod).